# problem in qt when added ros.h

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i added ros/ros.h include in my qt and when i run the program ther are problem that  :
/usr/include/qt4/ros/ros.h:38: error: ros/time.h: No such file or directory
and :
#include "ros/rate.h"
#include "ros/console.h"
#include "ros/assert.h"
#include "ros/types.h"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11650/problem-in-qt-when-added-ros.h/) by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> i added ros/ros.h include in my qt and
> when i run the program ther are
> problem that :
> /usr/include/qt4/ros/ros.h:38: error:
> ros/time.h: No such file or directory
> and :

This looks like you edited files in /usr/include, which you should never need to do!
Anyway, either you didn't install ros or you didn't specify to the compiler where to find it. There is no way to help you without more details about what you did.

However, since it looks like you don't know what you are doing in general (I am sorry if I am wrong here), I would recommend to have a look into basic tutorials for [programming c++ with ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2